# Is there a way to make a vnc server not user specific?

Tags: linux, centos-6, tigervnc

I am using tigervnc server on CentOS 6.8. I am trying to get it so that users can open their vnc viewer to say `ipaddress:5901` and the viewer will ask for both username and password. Right now I have it a user per port.

```
VNCSERVERS="1:someuser"
```

and I want it so each individual can open their vnc viewer and go to port 5901 and log in as themselves. Or perhaps not the same port but it still asks for their specific credentials and logs them into their own account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

use Xvnc instead. xvnc manages the X sessions and the logins so all logins go to the same port and sessions can be initiated by login.